# How to compare generics of same type?

Tags: java, generics, compare

I'm trying to compare two subclasses of Number inside a class with generics. In the code below, I'm trying to compare Number objects inside an instance of Datum.

How do I enforce that both parameters passed to the Datum constructor are of the same class, so that I can compare what I know to be comparable types - e.g. Float and Float, or Long and Long?

```
Float f1 = new Float(1.5);
Float f2 = new Float(2.5);

new Datum<Number>(f1, f2);

class Datum<T extends Number> {
    T x;
    T y;

Datum(T xNum, T yNum) {

    x = xNum;
    y = yNum;
            if (x > y) {} // does not compile

    }
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You could restrict it to `Comparable` subclasses of `Number`:

```
class Datum<T extends Number & Comparable<? super T>> {
  ...

  if (x.compareTo(y) > 0) { ... }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

try

```
if (((Comparable)x).compareTo((Comparable)y)>0) {}
```

instead of

```
if (x > y) {}
```

Comment: `Number` does not implement `Comparable`, so you'll have to cast the value to `Comparable`.

Comment: That wouldn't be a safe cast though, because not all Numbers are Comparable

Comment: Define reliably. :)  It'll work.  And it'll generate warnings.  Whether this is acceptable I leave to the OP.

Comment: I see. Is there a way to enforce that both parameters passed to the constructor are of the same Number sub-class? Otherwise the cast to Comparable isn't type safe, is it?

Comment: @danH, `T` must be one type or another.  Since both values will be of type `T`, it should be safe (assuming the type implements `Comparable` in the first place, unlike `AtomicInteger`).

Comment: @Kirk - I'm confused then. Isn't it possible to pass an Integer and a Long to the same contructor? Is there some hidden type conversion casting the second parameter to the class of the first?

Comment: @danH: It would be possible to pass an `Integer` and a `Long` to the constructor if you did `new Datum<Number>(...)`. If you did `new Datum<Integer>(...)` both parameters would have to be `Integer`.

Answer (score 1):

Compare the outcome of [`Number#doubleValue()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Number.html#doubleValue%28%29) instead.

```
if (x.doubleValue() > y.doubleValue()) {}
```

Comment: This is what I usually do.  Beware that this could fail with `BigDecimal` and `BigInteger` though.

Answer (score 1):

You could always compare the double values

```
return ((Double)x.doubleValue()).compareTo(y.doubleValue());
```

Comment: `Number#doubleValue()` doesn't return `Double`, but `double`. In other words, this ain't ever going to compile.

Comment: Also, my answer will just return the compareTo value, use @BalusC answer for the if (...) { }

Comment: And this will say that `Long.MAX_VALUE` and `LONG.MAX_VALUE -1` are equal.